# Node js: Express + ssh2 does NOT reset my data structures when loading web pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

To show jobs sent by users to a cluster I have the following code (simplified):

```
var split = require('split');
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;
var conn = new Client();

var globalRes;
var table = [["Head_1","Head_2"]];

module.exports = {
    renderTable: function(req, res) {

         conn.connect({host: 'xx.xx.xx.xx', port: 22, username: 'xxxxx', password: 'xxxxx'});

         globalRes = res;
         table = [["Head_1","Head_2"]];
         conn.on('ready', function() { conn.shell(doSomething);} );
    }
}

function doSomething(err, stream) {

    stream.on('close', function() {
         conn.end();
         globalRes.render('index', { HTMLtable: table });
         console.log(table);
    } );
    stream.pipe(split()).on('data', buildTable);
    stream.write('qstat -s z\n');
    stream.end('exit\n');
}

function buildTable(line) {
    var newLine = [1, 2];
    if(line.substring(0,6) == "job-ID") {
         table.push(newLine);
    }
    return;
}
```

It opens a ssh connection, after receiving the data it renders the page.

Problem: Only the first time it executes right, in our example console.log shows:

[ [ 'Head_1', 'Head_2' ], [ 1, 2 ] ]     <<< which is fine.

But from the first time on, every time the page is load the code piles on over the 'table' data structure. In other words, if we reload the page for a second time (or load the same page for first time in another browser) console.log shows:

[ [ 'Head_1', 'Head_2' ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2 ] ]

[ [ 'Head_1', 'Head_2' ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2 ] ]

So, not only 'table' is getting an additional row [1,2] (it shouldn't) but the command console.log is executed twice.

If we load the page a third time, now we get:

[ [ 'Head_1', 'Head_2' ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2 ] ]

[ [ 'Head_1', 'Head_2' ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2 ] ]

[ [ 'Head_1', 'Head_2' ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2 ] ]

'table' is growing as the times that console.log gets executed.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: My guess here is that table is in the global scope, thus the issues you see. Do something like this: tableMap["userName"] = {} where the {} is the table object as you currently use it. You could also use closures to resolve this issue.

Comment: You were right Michael, the variables in the global scope were causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem solved. I'm posting just in case other person has a similar problem and this may shed some light.

It was due to my Javascript bad coding practices. It works if you include everything inside the function renderTable, this is ZERO (0) global variables.

All functions, all variables (IMPORTANT: including the 'require()'s) inside:

```
module.exports = {
    renderTable: function(req, res) {

           <<<< Put everything here.

    }
}
```

In fact, this way the variable 'globalRes' is unnecessary, just use 'res' as it should be.

Hope this helps. I'm not going to mark my own answer as correct so if anyone wants to get technical and explain the specific reason why it failed I'll check that answer as correct.